# циклический сдвиг битов вправо

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

Ниже представлен рабочий код, но почему-то выводятся лишние нули после D. Объясните почему так происходит?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int ror(int a, int n)

{

  int t1, t2;

  n = n % (sizeof(a)*8);  // нормализуем n

  t1 = a >> n;   // двигаем а влево на n бит, теряя младшие биты

  t2 = a << (sizeof(a)*8 - n); // перегоняем младшие биты в старшие

  return t1 | t2;  // объединяем старшие и младшие биты

}

int main()
{
    printf("%x", ror(0xFFAD, 4));

    return 0;
}
```

Console output:

```
ad0000ff
```

Comment: я подробнее напишу. тип int занимает 4 байта в памяти. и ваше число FFAD на самом деле 0000FFAD, при сдвиге получается AD0000FF

Comment: Не `sizeof(a)*8`, а `sizeof(a) * CHAR_BIT`. Что за магические константы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int ror(int a, int n)
```

Тип int - это 32битное число. 32 бита это 4 байта, 4 байта - 8 символов в 16ричной системе. То есть передавая в функцию 0xFFAD вы на самом деле передаете 0x0000FFAD, и сдвигая на 4 бита получаете 0xAD0000FF. Ваша функция работает правильно

Если вы хотите именно 16битные числа смещать - измените тип параметра на short, получите то что вы ожидали. Если нули в начале должны игнорироваться - придется модифицировать функцию